# Sending notification vscode.json-language-features server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My issue in short:

I have built an extension, that does additional json validation, completion, definitions.
So far - the extension relyed on json schemas in client's settings.json for the main validation.
Now I have to make that part dynamic - when client installs a specific npm package, I have to find in it's node modules that definition, and provide it for specific files. So far - have made that part - gathering schemas, and fileMatch them. I have them in a format of `ISchemaAssociation` ([Ref](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/0425f27e47df678e36fbf3edf2ddc8b320ad1420/extensions/json-language-features/client/src/jsonClient.ts#L46)). I was thinking - if only I could send [This](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/0425f27e47df678e36fbf3edf2ddc8b320ad1420/extensions/json-language-features/client/src/jsonClient.ts#L309) notification to json language server - it could provide those schemas to the client.

I was even looking by requiring this extension as a dependency, but looks like - it has no exports ([Ref to extenions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#extensions)... So I have no way to get any piece of it.

// If it had exported a function like `notifySchemaAssociations(associations: IAssociation[])`, and I would call it - it would work, since it would notify jsonServer > vscode-json-languageservice, right?

One way - I did make this work - was to build my language server as a pretty much copy-paste from [jsonServer.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/0425f27e47df678e36fbf3edf2ddc8b320ad1420/extensions/json-language-features/server/src/jsonServer.ts), which uses `vscode-json-languageservice` that does all of the standard json stuff. But this does not feel right...

By looking further into `json-language-features` - found - that it's inputs are either settings.json / global settings, and other extension `contributes.jsonValidation`. So I think, I will make my extension update client's `settings.json`... This is not targeted for public use, just for internal and for some users.